# DataGridView fails SelectedCells property

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, cells

in my project I have 3 DataGridView and I need to retrieve the SelectedCells of the grid
in 2 grids this works fine, but in one ( and the code is exactly the same of the other 2)
the grid.SelectedCells.Count is 1 but If I go in the inspector to view which cell is selected, the result is 0,0...

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, sorry everybody, but before check the selected cells, i made a Fill of the dataset, and this caused the problem...